# Drag & Drop items between tableViews in same viewController and different viewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, drag-and-drop, tableview

I need to Drag and Drop items between tableViews inside the same viewController and between tableviews in different viewControllers. I researched for ways to do this and if there's already any good library. I didn't find anything that does all this so I'll try do from scratch, maybe a combination from [this](http://www.ancientprogramming.com/2012/04/05/drag-and-drop-between-multiple-uiviews-in-ios/)! and [this project](https://github.com/shusta/ReorderingTableViewController)!

Quite a challenge but my main concern is how to recognize a dragged cell from one view to the other. My idea is to create a parentViewController, common to the viewControllers containing the tableviews and then add a gesture recognizer in the parentViewController so when the item is dropped is not needed to translate the position of one view to another and simply try to identify if the item´s position crosses a view in the same reference system. What you guys think? I would like to know your opinions and expertises for the best way to do this. Or if there's a good project that I can start from there...

Thank you

Comment: were you able to achieve this ?

Comment: Yes I was. Do you need to do something similar?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this following-

1. One parentVC which containing two VC,AVC and BVC
2. You need to create table View custom (using scroll view)
3. Each cell in custom table view has on LongPressed gesture which tells to prentVC
   I am selected after that on movement of finger move cell (Setting .center property of
   cell)
4. After dropping check his position of X or Y and adds in another view

Comment: Why is necessary to create a custom tableView? Doesn't the same works with a normal tableView? I'll try adding a longPress gesture to every cell...

Comment: Yes this works with normal table view but when we create custom table view we have full control on it and this will be good structure when we need to add some another functionality in less time

Answer (score 0):

Just released an open source framework that can achieve this: [BetweenKit](https://github.com/ice3-software/between-kit)

There is an example application that can demonstrates recognising drag/drops between 2 controllers using BetweenKit [here](https://github.com/ice3-software/between-kit/tree/master/Use%20Cases/20.%20Split%20View%20Controller).

Hope this helps.